# iOS Z-order of UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, calayer, quartz-2d

How can I get the Z-order of a `UIView` in regards to the key window?

The heirarchy depth is not of interest to me. I don't care about how many superviews to the key window.

Just want to know which views appear "closer" to the user.

I've tried various possibilities such as

```
hittesting
view.layer.depth
post-order DFS (Or some sort of variation)
```

but this resulting answer is in regards to its "surroundings" and not the actual "painting order" of the view on the screen.

Is this possible in a reasonable fashion?

Answer (score 0):

UIView siblings are stacked in the order in which they are added to their superview.

You can check with the following code:

View on top: 
`[parentView.subviews lastObject];`

View at the bottom: 
`[parentView.subviews objectAtIndex:0];`

If you want a view to appear in front of all other views:

```
[parentView bringSubviewToFront:view]
```

Comment: I know this. but it doesn't guarantee that one is above the other in respect to a cousin view in the hierarchy.

Comment: Also a view can be clear and an underlying view will be visible. I am only interested in the views which are actually visible to the user. I am not creating a view heir achy. I am inspecting a view hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

The order of which views appear in subviews array determines their Z-order. If View A is added before View B using addSubView() then View B will be above View A.